# Forwarding external to internal port on azure: not accepting external connections

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, azure

I have a service running on `localhost:8111` on an Ubuntu 16.04 VM in Azure, and I'm trying to forward external traffic on port 80 to `localhost:8111`.  However, external traffic is being rejected and I can't see what I've done wrong.

On the Ubuntu VM I edited `/etc/sysctl.conf` and uncommented this line:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

After rebooting, I added the following to iptables so that I could access port 80 port internally and externally:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8111
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8111
```

After doing that, I can verify that the port works *from within the Ubuntu VM* with `curl http://localhost:80` and using the external address via `curl http://example.org`.

However, I can't access `http://example.org` from the internet.

I have an Azure `Network Interface` attached to the VM, set to 10.0.1.5, and it has a static Public IP, and `IP Forwarding` set to `enabled`.  It is attached to a NSG that allows traffic on port 80 with `any` source and `any` destination

I think this should work---I can't see what I've done wrong.

Here's the output of `iptables -t nat --list`:

```
~$ sudo iptables -t nat --list
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http redir ports 8111

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http redir ports 8111

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one additional change we need to make:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1
```

By default this value is 0, which instructs the kernel to not route external traffic destined to 127.0.0.0/8. **This is just for security as such traffic is not normal.**

The iptables rule like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:8111
```

Here is my test:

Ubuntu 16.04:

Private IP address: 10.0.1.4
Public IP address: 104.41.185.158
apache2 listen on localhost port 8111

```
root@jasonvm:/etc/apache2# netstat -ant | grep 8111
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8111          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work!  When you say "such traffic is not normal", are you implying that there are extra security implications of doing that?

Comment: Also, I'm not clear why your DNAT statement works but my REDIRECT does not---I thought REDIRECT was essentially a DNAT but with an implicit route to localhost....